# Question with some problematic traits (little practical use / setting restrictions on method), but is it sufficient reason for closing it?

Tags: discussion, questions, deleted-questions

I recently asked a purely theoretical, and possibly useless, question about Java stream expressions. Specifically I'm refering to [Is it possible to construct a Java stream expression to return a 2D boolean array, all values set to true?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64287048/is-it-possible-to-construct-a-java-stream-expression-to-return-a-2d-boolean-arra)

It got closed so I was just left wondering what the problem was exactly and should like to know what people's opinions are. This question seems ok to me (more or less), so I am a little perplexed. But I got the feeling that the restrictions I outlined for the method was creating a solution people were considering non-optimal or non-standard. If this were the case is this still good enough reason for closing it?

If there are other problems that I'm missing please help me understand. Perhaps, is it possible to make it acceptable? (Do note actually, it has been edited during this process, but it's still the same question)

Comment: I don't understand why that post is closed. It's perfectly clear to me.

Comment: IMO, the close reason chosen is trash, it's perfectly clear what's being asked. That said, there's a lot of noise in the question which detracts from the question itself: *"Please be aware, the question is purely motivated by learning ... don't necessarily expect this to be the most practical way of initialising an array!"* is simply noise and would be better suited in a comment under the question and the full background about "[xxx] works with ints, but [yyy] does not seem to work with bools" could be written far more concisely. It's an untidy question, but it's not awful

Comment: @Nick Thanks I agree, I edited that out.

Comment: *"[..] the restrictions I outlined for the method was creating a solution people were considering non-optimal or non-standard. If this were the case is this still good enough reason for closing it?"* ... no it isn't. Such questions are fine and the answers can teach about the limitations and boundaries of functions/features/etc and how proper approaches can look like. That's why I voted to reopen the question.

Comment: @Tom many thanks for that, that helps my confidence. I'm very surprised how this question seems to be dividing opinions ..

Comment: The meta effect has reopened the question, which is nice.

Comment: possibly related: [Why is "Is it possible to:" a poorly worded question?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7274/31260)

Comment: I'll repeat it here: you edited your solution into the question, you shouldn't do that. Post the solution as an answer instead.

Comment: It's funny, because it's supposed that all questions here are practical. CompSci deals with the theory.

Comment: @Gimby point taken thanks! I posted the answer I had separately

Answer (score 6):

I cannot speak for the close voters on your question as I was not one, but as a guess I would say that they voted as such because the question lacks a "why".

In and of itself this is not an issue, but when you couple it with the fact that your question is, at face value, asking how to do something that appears unnecessary and/or complex and/or plain dumb, the question starts to look like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

XY problem questions are some of the most reviled on the network, because they almost always end up wasting the valuable time of people who answer them at face value. Then the asker posts a comment on the answer saying that it doesn't work, and the answerer gets into a whole comment chain of trying to squeeze blood (the actual problem) out of a stone (the asker). And 9 times out of 10, it turns out that the asker doesn't understand the actual problem, or it cannot be solved, or it's completely unrelated to the question asked, or it would easily be solved if the asker had spent 5 seconds using their damn brain instead of running to Stack Overflow.

If you're lucky, someone will have already posted a comment on the question asking for the "why" before you post an answer, and the asker's response will demonstrate that the question is an XY problem, at which time you can go do something else while you wait for others to squeeze the blood from that stone.

If you're *really* lucky, you'll arrive at the question by the time all this has gone down and revealed the actual problem to be not understood/nonsensical/unsolvable, and can cast a quick close vote to get it consigned to the depths of hell from whence it came.

In short, **always include the why when asking a question here**. "Research purposes" or "s**ts and giggles" or "simple curiosity" are all valid reasons. Without that reason, we close voters will generally assume you don't know what you're asking about, and thus vote on your question accordingly.